# After account creation, UI fails on previously loaded pages

Tags: bug, voting, user-accounts

After creating a new account, actions taken on pages opened prior to account creation fail, and the info/error messages about those actions also fail. Yes, this is an edge case, but a bug nonetheless.

Step-by-step event timeline:

1. A long time ago, I created accounts on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange and other SE sites, but **not** Travel Stack Exchange
2. While logged into Meta SE, I opened several Travel SE questions in different tabs
3. On one of those Travel SE tabs, I clicked the "Join this community" button at the top of the page
4. I clicked the "Confirm new account" button, agreeing to the site's terms and conditions; this actually created the Travel-specific account and linked it with my existing network profile
5. On the next page, I verified that the account was created, and that the 100-point association bonus appeared
6. In a separate, Travel SE tab, already open from before I created the Travel SE account, I clicked a question's upvote button
7. The system did not register the vote, and displayed an empty white box over part of the question (in hindsight, it looks like it was probably intended to contain the "Join this site" prompt)

[image: Page after clicking upvote button, with highlighted but unchanged vote indicator and white box over content]

I didn't see any error messages or guidance from the system on the page. I didn't think to open the inspector before refreshing, though. After refreshing the page, my new account's identicon and reputation appeared in the header, and I was able to cast a vote normally.

Comment: I suppose you could call that a bug... but that's usually how things work when you meddle with authentication across multiple tabs / windows. Fixing that requires inter-document communication which is not especially easy or quick to implement. Out of curiosity, have you tried the same thing with other services like e.g. Google or Amazon? What were the results?

Comment: I have not. I saw weird behavior and I reported it, that's all.

Comment: No offense meant, just saying the probabilities of this being fixed are pretty low.

Comment: None taken, and I didn't expect it to be fixed quickly (or ever). Just thought it should be recorded somewhere.